# AngularJS coupling between view and controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an AngularJS application in which I started off with my view files having the controller defined using the `ng-controller` directive.

**myview.html**

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">
   <ul>
     <li class="thumb" ng-repeat="item in items">
         <span profile ng-click="getItem(item.id)"></span>
     </li>      
   </ul> 
</div>
```

However, I am now using routing and my controller is defined as part of my routeProvider configuration.

**myview.html**

```
<div>
   <ul>
     <li class="thumb" ng-repeat="item in items">
         <span profile ng-click="getItem(item.id)"></span>
     </li>      
   </ul> 
</div>
```

**router.js**

```
.when('/homepage', {
   templateUrl: 'templates/myview.html',
   controller: 'MyController'
})
```

This works, but although at first it seemed like this was helping me to decouple my view from my controller, something feels off as I still have references to scope member variables in my view and these are tied to my controller.

Am I missing something here? What have I gained from specifying `MyController` in my routeProvider and not in my template?

Comment: You can use different controllers for the same template, if they fulfill the same contract (required by the template). An example usage would be to have a view in which users with different roles, have different capabilities. You could have a separate controller for each role.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For all practical purposes I don't believe you gained anything, except from conforming to the standard way of defining routes, views and controllers in AngularJS.

If we're thinking programming principles and MVC, your view now doesn't know anything about the controller, it is only dependent on the model (that'd be `$scope` in angular), which is fine and perfectly normal in a MVC-architecture.

Answer (score 1):

By defining the  controller in your route, you can use the same view (template) in multiple controller (and pass different scoped data)

For example:

```
.when('/homepage', {
   templateUrl: 'templates/myview.html',
   controller: 'MyController'
})
.when('/list', {
   templateUrl: 'templates/myview.html',
   controller: 'MyListController'
})
```